# For which $d$ holds $\lim_{t\to \infty} |W_t|=\infty$?

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, stochastic-analysis

> Let $(W_t)_{t\ge 0}$ be a Wiener process in $\mathbb R^d, d \ge 1$. For which $d$ holds $\lim_{t\to \infty} |W_t|=\infty$? Provide complete proof of this property/lack of this property for those $d$ for which it holds/does not hold.

I have no idea what properties of the Wiener process I could use to solve this problem. I tried using the law of the iterated logarithm, but didn't get anything helpful.

Comment: In [Moerters-Peres](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/brownian-motion/F639B9A8403BD465F896F3E18A9C3382) you can find the arguments of point recurrence/neighbourhood recurrence/transience of Brownian motion depending on $d$.